# Hide user credentials shown in the browser while OOTB login

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

Is there a way to hide user credentials shown in the browser while OOTB login?
As shown below, When inspect user credentials are shown in browser and this has raised a security concern.
[image]

Comment: Don't think there's much you can do about it for password grant type. Consider another grant type for your auth if you are concern about security. Here's a good read https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

Comment: Spartacus supports various oauth flows. see docs https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/session-management/#configuring-authorization-code-flow-or-implicit-flow

Comment: @platonn Thanks for reply. But we need to use OOTB login and hide the credentials from formData. Can you please help how we can achieve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a non-issue.

(I'm assuming of course you are using http**s**)

Yes, you submit the username and password as clear text, but it is transmitted over an **encrypted connection**.

That's how the internet works.

Don't believe me? Go to your bank's website, Amazon, ... and monitor the traffic in the browser dev tools.

You will see exactly the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways of hiding user credentials.

If the site is delivered over HTTPS then all transmissions will be encrypted and you probably wont be able to see username and password in the browser (not 100% sure on this).

Secondly, you could encrypt the username and password using some method and decrypt it on your server. e.g. base 64 encoding using the JavaScript atob function. However, for anyone in the know they could easily decode it so you probably want something more advanced. Certainly you would want something more advanced than base 64 encoding, although it might appease your boss.

Thirdly, you could use something like JWT. You send username and password in HTTP login request to your server. The server checks the credentials and if valid returns a cookie. The cookie should be HTTP only. You should set the cookie using the Set-Cookie response header from your server. This is the most secure approach. When the cookie is set in this way it is automatically sent in all subsequent requests to that domain (until it expires based on the expiration time you set when you created it on the server). Moreover, it cannot be access by JavaScript, only your server can access it - making it highly secure. On all incoming requests (except the login request) the server checks for the token and checks it's valid.